# Given a binary matrix of 0 and 1. Find the longest sequence of 1's either row wise or column wise

Tags: javascript, matrix

Given a binary matrix of 0 and 1. Find the longest sequence of 1's either row wise or column wise.
For example:

0 0 0 1 0 0

0 0 1 1 0 0

0 0 0 1 0 0

It should return highest count – 3.
Help, write this program on js

```
  var cols = prompt("input cols", 4);
  var rows = prompt("input rows", 4);
  var arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      arr[i] = [];

      for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
          var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 1);
          arr[i][j] = rand;
      }
  }

  console.log(arr);

  var str = arr.join('\n');
  console.log(str);

  var List = str.split(0);
   //----there is a code for  continuous sequence
  var max = 0;
  var array = str.split('1').forEach(function (item) {
      if (max < item.length) max = item.length;
  })
```

How to search by rows and columns to find an uninterrupted sequence

Comment: Is your matrix a 2d array? Please specify the data-structure you have used and your attempt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: You need to add the details to your question only. It is unlikely that every expert here will read the details from comments.

Comment: @gurvinder372 ok) thx )

Comment: @Andreas 

I edited the question,
How to search by rows and columns to find an uninterrupted sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var max_1_row = -1;
var row_num = -1
var max_1_col = -1;
var col_num = -1
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var max_1_in_row = 0;
    var max_1_in_row_seq = 0;
    var max_1_in_col = 0;
    var max_1_in_col_seq = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
            max_1_in_row += arr[i][j];
        } else {
            max_1_in_row = 0;
        }
        if (max_1_in_row > max_1_in_row_seq) {
            max_1_in_row_seq = max_1_in_row;
        }
//By Column
        if (arr[j][i] == 1) {
            max_1_in_col += arr[j][i];
        } else {
            max_1_in_col = 0;
        }
        if (max_1_in_col > max_1_in_col_seq) {
            max_1_in_col_seq = max_1_in_col;
        }
    }
    if (max_1_in_row_seq > max_1_row) {
        max_1_row = max_1_in_row_seq;
        row_num = i + 1;
    }
    if (max_1_in_col_seq > max_1_col) {
        max_1_col = max_1_in_col_seq;
        col_num = i + 1;
    }
}
```

console.log("Row:" + max_1_row + " in row " + row_num + "\n Column:" + max_1_col + " in column " + col_num);

Comment: This is just a quick code. This code may be simplify more.